# RGB digital to analog converter

Tags: led-driver, dac, led-strip, rgb

I am seeking help to design a small PCB that can translate digital RGB like Neopixel to analog signals for driving high current LED RGB. I know it's a bit weird. I would like to connect to a board that I know is sending Neopixel code (WS2812.) I don't want an LED strip with WS2812, but instead a high current LED strip.
I have been looking at the UCS8904 which is 16-bit LED driver.

I would very much appriciate some help to get started. I hope the question is clear enough.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WS2812 protocol is based on different high/low times to encode bits, it's non standard, and pretty fast (~1-2µs/bit).

You could use a microcontroller but it will have to run code in a tight loop to measure timings and won't be able to do anything else. Or a CPLD.

But the simplest would be to use [WS2811](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf) to decode the protocol: it's the same chip that's integrated inside WS2812's but without LEDs. It outputs constant current chopped by PWM.

[image]

So if you replace the LEDs with pullup resistors, say above 220 ohms, for example 1kOhm, you'll get a PWM voltage output compatible with 5V logic levels.

If you want to drive your high power LEDs with PWM, then you can use a logic gate inverter to drive the gate of a common source MOSFET.

If you want to use a switching constant current driver, then you have to convert the PWM signal into whatever input your driver wants to regulate current.

Answer (score 2):

To complement on @bobflux, if you're interested in running on 24V you should look at the WS2814. You will need to put some LEDs in series to get close to your power supply voltage (ideally 6 for 24V) to limit the voltage drop that the chip will see and then reduce it's power dissipation.
I've been working on custom LED bars using those with 4 LEDs in series and a 17V power supply to reduce power dissipation in the WS2814, it's been working pretty well and efficiently.